# Postgres-case when

Tags: postgresql

```
select x.codigo,x.nome,x.cpf,x.contato,
x.limite_credito,
x.pendencia as pendencia

 from

( select p.codigo,p.cpf,p.contato,p.limite_credito,p.grid,p.grupo,p.nome,
p.flag,p.tipo,m.child,m.pessoa,coalesce(sum(valor),0) as pendencia from 
movto m join pessoa p on m.pessoa=p.grid 

where m.child=0 and m.data between'2017-05-01' and '2017-05-05' and m.conta_debitar='1.3.03' 
group by m.pessoa,m.child,p.tipo,p.flag,p.nome,p.limite_credito,
p.grupo,p.grid,p.codigo,p.cpf
) as x

left join pessoa_conta pc on pc.pessoa=x.pessoa 
join grupo_pessoa gp on gp.grid=x.grupo
join pessoa pe on pe.grid=x.grid
and x.nome!='CONSUMIDOR FINAL' 
and x.child=0
and x.flag='A'
AND X.tipo='CU'
group by x.nome,x.pendencia,x.tipo,x.codigo,x.cpf,x.contato,pc.lim_credito,x.limite_credito
order by 1
```

Fiz o script acima em Postgres 9.4, mas se o campo limite de crédito for nulo ele não soma com outro limite de notas (fiado). Ao que parece tenho que zerar o campo que vem como `null`, estava pensando em usar `case when`, mas dá erro. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Lembre-se de que qualquer operação envolvendo um campo NULL dará como resultado um NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Sua lógica de agregação com o `sum` e o `coalesce` me parece estar incorreta.

Tente substituir:

```
coalesce(sum(valor),0) as pendencia
```

Por:

```
sum(coalesce(valor,0)) as pendencia
```

Mas se você ainda prefere usar o `CASE WHEN`:

```
sum(CASE WHEN valor IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE valor END) as pendencia
```

Answer (score -1):

Use o `coalesce`:

```
Coalesce(p.limite_credito,0) as limite_credito
```

Essa função retorna o primeiro parâmetro que não seja nulo. No seu caso, quando `p.limite_credito` for nulo, irá retornar 0.

Você também pode usa-lá com mais parametros:

```
Coalesce(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

Mais informações em: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: melhorou ? pelo que eu entendi da questão dele é apenas isso